# PHP extract function for $_FILES variable

Tags: php, arrays, file, variables, web

I want to upload more than one file from a single form and in next page I want to use `extract()` method for extracting the contents of the `$_FILE` variable.
The names of the file which are chosen are stored in `$_FILE` variable.
I'm using `extract($_FILE)` but its not working.

Comment: not file "FILES" try this print_r($_FILES);  extract is used for make array key as variable

Comment: global variable $_FILES not $_FILE

Answer (score 0):

First up, you need to provide code in your question.
Just read the PHP Manual, there is even a page dedicated for uploading multiple files at one, you can find it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php).

The data of the files are stored in an seperate array for name, size etc and not in an array per file.

Example: You got two files, file1.png and file2.png then it would be something like this (copied from the php manual page):

```
Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => file1.png
            [1] => file2.png
        )

    [type] => Array
        (
            [0] => text/plain
            [1] => text/plain
        )

    [tmp_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => /tmp/phpYzdqkD
            [1] => /tmp/phpeEwEWG
        )

    [error] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
        )

    [size] => Array
        (
            [0] => 123
            [1] => 456
        )
)
```

Look here [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) what and why you should always provide a code sample.

Answer (score 0):

[refernce link](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php)

1)Superglobal variable $_FILES not $_FILE

2)print_r($_FILES); or var_dump($_FILES);

```
Superglobal Description
$_FILES['my-file']['name']  Original Name of File Before It Was Uploaded
$_FILES['my-file']['type']  The MIME Type of File, Provided By the Browser
$_FILES['my-file']['size']  Size of the File (In Bytes)
$_FILES['my-file']['tmp_name']  Location of Temporary File on Server
```

**NOTE:**
     The extract() function imports variables into the local symbol table from    an array.

This function uses array keys as variable names and values as variable values. For each element it will create a variable